PHP crypt returns *0 in different PHP version
I used crypt() for password on my site and I just noticed the code in server with php 5.6.40 it's fine but in 8.2.12 it returns *0
I noticed if I change the ! to something else then it works but I need to keep it the same as users password already been saved.
Anyone has the same issue and know why?
$password = "Test@1234";
$crypt_password = crypt($password, "aKsCg#ZTP6!$");
echo "crypt_password: $crypt_password <br>";


Have you checked release notes in between?

https://3v4l.org/aef3p - I doubt it's down to the PHP version alone. The crypt docs say "Using invalid characters in the salt will cause crypt() to fail" and I expect that's what's happening here.

I didn't see anything about crypt in release notes for 8.2.12

But it worked in other php version with the same code. If there's invalid characters then it should failed on all php version?

I tried in wamp with same version and it works so don't think it's version. Maybe it's more to the server or something with php package but I can't tell what could be related or missing.

PHP in the past was very tolerant.

I don't know much about this specific function, but the 8.0 migration guide says "The deprecated DES fallback in crypt() has been removed. If an unknown salt format is passed to crypt(), the function will fail with *0 instead of falling back to a weak DES hash now."
